# Setting up HelixBase with Sitecore 9.1 and unsure how to run Unicorn

Tags: helix, unicorn

I am trying to follow the instructions for setting up the HelixBase solution, using these instructions. https://github.com/muso31/Helixbase

Unfortunately on step 5 I'm a bit lost.

What do I need to do to run Unicorn?

To confirm what I have tried - I have restored nuget packages, built the solution and used the publish all projects gulp task.  I have tried logging into sitecore admin and then changing the url to http://demo.helixbase.sc/unicorn.aspx

[image]

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the HelixBase project and which version of Unicorn it uses. However we recently released some fixes for Unicorn and Sitecore 9.0x/9.1 - try updating your Unicorn package to version 4.0.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sitecore 9.1 uses identity server for authorization. **muso31/Helixbase** uses unicorn 4.0.4 and old version of Rainbow.

Just update Unicorn to 4.0.7 version and Rainbow to 2.0.5. There are some changes in unicorn config files for new version. Be sure to update them https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Unicorn/tree/master/src/Unicorn/Standard%20Config%20Files

Comment: In terms of the config changes.  Do I need to add the Unicorn.UI.IdentityServer.config file if I'm using Sitecore 9.1 locally?  helixbase is throwing a different error whether I have this file or disable it.  Is that the only config change that is required for these new versions?  Or did I miss reading a summary type page that explicitly said what had changed in 9.1.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok so it helps that I restart IIS and have that confi enabled.  I am now getting an error: Cannot activate Unicorn.Deserialization.UnicornDeserializer, constructor param 'ignoreBranchId' (Boolean). The type 'Boolean' is probably not registered, or may need to be an explicit unmapped parameter (as an XML attribute on the type registration). Inner message: Cannot construct System.Boolean because it has no constructor!

Comment: New version of UnicornDeserializer (4.0.7) has constructor parameter ignoreBranchId. You can see it here https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Unicorn/blob/master/src/Unicorn/Standard%20Config%20Files/Unicorn.config

Be sure that you updated your config.
<deserializer type="Unicorn.Deserialization.UnicornDeserializer, Unicorn" ignoreBranchId="true" singleInstance="true" />

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned, updating to 4.0.7 will resolve the issue, the reason you are seeing the *Cannot construct System.Boolean because it has no constructor* error is because you have not added all relevant Unicorn configs. I have now updated Helix Base to Unicorn 4.0.7 and if you pull the latest changes you can see the relevant configs updated in the **App_Config/Include/Unicorn** folder